# Tactic failure: Use forward_call W. method signature

Tags: verification, coq, verifiable-c

I try to verify my program with VST. I've got a weird error message:

```
Coq <  Check ( (sh, n, guess-1, vn, Vint (Int.sub (Int.repr guess) (Int.repr 1)))).
  > (sh, n, guess - 1, vn, Vint (Int.sub (Int.repr guess) (Int.repr 1)))
  >     : share * Z * Z * val * val
```

For me it seems like the function signature, that I'm going to use to `forward_call` is exactly what is reqired here (`share * Z * Z * val * val`)

```
Coq <  forward_call (sh,n,guess-1,vn,Vint (Int.sub (Int.repr guess) (Int.repr 1))).
  > Toplevel input, characters 0-75:
  > Error: Tactic failure: Use forward_call W, where W is a witness of type 
  > (share * Z * Z * val * val)%type 
  > (level 1).
```

But VST complains. Where should I look? What is different here ?

BTW, if it's useful, my intermediate proof state:
    1 focused subgoals (unfocused: 1-0-0)
    , subgoal 1 (ID 4026)

```
  Espec : OracleKind
  sh : share
  n : Z
  guess : Z
  vn : val
  vguess : val
  H : repr n vn
  H0 : repr guess vguess
  A0 : 0 <= n
  AM : n < Int.modulus
  B0 : 0 <= guess
  BM : guess * guess < Int.modulus
  Struct_env := abbreviate : type_id_env.type_id_env
  narg : name _n
  guessarg : name _guess
  Delta := abbreviate : tycontext
  POSTCONDITION := abbreviate : ret_assert
  ============================
   semax Delta
     (PROP  (repr guess vguess /\ guess > 0)
      LOCAL 
      (`(typed_false
           (typeof
              (Ebinop Ole
                 (Ebinop Omul (Etempvar _guess tuint) 
                    (Etempvar _guess tuint) tuint) 
                 (Etempvar _n tuint) tint)))
         (eval_expr
            (Ebinop Ole
               (Ebinop Omul (Etempvar _guess tuint) 
                  (Etempvar _guess tuint) tuint) (Etempvar _n tuint) tint));
      `(eq vguess) (eval_id _guess); `(eq vn) (eval_id _n))  
      SEP())
     (Ssequence
        (Scall (Some 38%positive)
           (Evar _guess_sqrt
              (Tfunction (Tcons tuint (Tcons tuint Tnil)) tuint cc_default))
           [Etempvar _n tuint;
           Ebinop Osub (Etempvar _guess tuint) (Econst_int (Int.repr 1) tint)
             tuint]) (Sreturn (Some (Etempvar 38%positive tuint))))
     (overridePost (PROP  ()  LOCAL ()  SEP()) POSTCONDITION)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess_sqrt_spec has an error in line 68 of verif_sqrt.v,
where you give the return type as "tint" (signed integer) where
the sqrt.c program has "tuint" (unsigned integer).

Then the VST's forward_call tactic has a misleading and 
unhelpful error message, complaining about the witness type
instead of the return-type mismatch.